# Loop through numbers with a step - PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm new on programming and I've tried to print a list of numbers with a step of 3, basically the first number remains the same 3 times but the second one increments 3 times. Here is pattern i want to achieve:

```
01-01
01-02
01-03
02-01
02-02
02-03
...
11-01
11-02
11-03
12-01
...
```

What I've tried so far:

```
for($a=0; $a <= 3; $a++){
   for($b=1; $b <= 3; $b++){
       echo $a.$b. "-" .$a.$b."<br";
   }
}
```

My Output:

```
01-01
02-02
03-03
```

Any idea on how to print the first element 3 times before incrementing? Thanks.

Comment: You've basically achieved this already, but  your output format is a bit confusing. Try using `echo $a . "-" . $b . PHP_EOL;` instead and it will hopefully be more clear. Also starting with `$a=1` in your outer loop. [like so](https://3v4l.org/kNEE3)

Comment: @Gavin Thank you, it was just in front of my eyes, I didnt see it. Thats exactly the result I needed, I've just modified the code a little to this for a better format:
`echo $a . $b . PHP_EOL . "<br>";`

Answer (score 1):

```
$to = 15; // to what number
for($a=1; $a <= $to; $a++){ // this loop will take number from 1 to $to
   for($b=1; $b <= 3; $b++){ //this loop will do the printing three times
       echo $a. "-" .$b."<br";
   }
}
```

Hope this helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input but the result is not what I've needed.
Your code simply returns the following value:
1-1